# PlayStation Blog ID not working for Flickr api with Jquery mobile

Tags: api, flickr

Hi I am currently trying to get the PlayStation Blog from flickr api working but the ID I get for PlayStation is not working with Jquery Mobile can anyone help?

This is the ID I get for the blog 8309149@N08

Here is the relevant HTML code as I am trying to display the images in a grid format.

```
<section id="photos" class="header_default footer_default" data-role="page" data-title="Photo grid">
    <div data-role="content">
      <div class="ui-grid-c" id="photolist"></div>
    </div><!-- content -->
  </section><!-- photos page -->

  <section id="showphoto" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
      <div id="myphoto"></div>
    </div><!-- content -->
  </section><!-- show photo page -->
<script src="http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=8309149@N08&format=json&tags=viewsource"></script>
```

Here is the Javascript

```
function jsonFlickrFeed(data) {
  var output = '';

  for (var i=0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
    var title = data.items[i].title;
    var link = data.items[i].media.m.substring(0,56);
    var blocktype = 
      ((i % 4) === 3) ? 'd':
      ((i % 4) === 2) ? 'c':
      ((i % 4) === 1) ? 'b':
      'a';
    output += '<div class="ui-block-' + blocktype + '">';
    output += '<a href="#showphoto" data-transition="fade" onclick="showPhoto(\'' + link + '\',\'' + title + '\')">';
    output += '<img src="' + link + '_q.jpg" alt="' + title + '">';
    output += '</a>';
    output += '</div>';
  }
  $('#photolist').html(output);
}

function showPhoto(link, title) {
  var output = '<a href="#photos" data-transition="fade">';
  output +='<img src="' + link +'_b.jpg" alt="' + title + '">';
  output +='</a>';
  $('#myphoto').html(output);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you're using to fetch images doesn't return any results.  `http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=8309149@N08&format=json&tags=viewsource` returns 0 images tagged with `viewsource`.  Try `http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=8309149@N08&format=json`.

Comment: Thank you so much. There are still some images that aren't loading up but I think it has something to do with PlayStations Blog.